# How to make brightness change permanent in iOS?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

```
GSEventSetBacklightLevel(BrightnessSlider.value); 

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setBacklightLevel:BrightnessSlider.value];
```

iOS UIScreen has brightness property. Setting it to a different value updates screen brightness. But after lock / unlock screen brightness is restored to whatever brightness is set in iOS Settings.

Must I make a call to save the setting? Is there a sync call or something?

This is a jailbreak development，No "sandbox"。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIApplication` `setBacklightLevel:` call is indeed temporary.

However, if you look at the code to toggle (change) brightness level in SBSettings, that is a permanent setting.  I do still think that any change in brightness is also affected by whether or not the user has the **Settings -> Brightness -> Auto-Brightness** feature turned on.  **Auto-Brightness** will dynamically adjust the screen brightness.

Take a look [at this page](http://thebigboss.org/guides-iphone-ipod-ipad/sbsettings-toggle-spec).  Scroll to the bottom to [see this link](http://thebigboss.org/hostedfiles/Brightness.zip).

As you can see, a permanent brightness change is achieved by writing the new brightness level to the **com.apple.springboard.plist** file:

```objc
    NSMutableDictionary* Prefs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.springboard.plist"];

    if(Prefs != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Prefs != nil\n");
        float CurrentBacklight1 = [[Prefs objectForKey:@"SBBacklightLevel"] floatValue];
        float CurrentBacklight2 = [[Prefs objectForKey:@"SBBacklightLevel2"] floatValue];
        NSNumber* Number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:CurrentBacklight];

        if(CurrentBacklight2 > 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"CurrentBacklight2 = %f\n", CurrentBacklight2);
            [Prefs setObject:Number forKey:@"SBBacklightLevel2"];
        }
        if(CurrentBacklight1 > 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"CurrentBacklight1 = %f\n", CurrentBacklight1);
            [Prefs setObject:Number forKey:@"SBBacklightLevel"];
        }
        [Prefs writeToFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.springboard.plist" atomically:YES];
    }
```

which contains the values that you are seeing SpringBoard *revert* to.  And, then the change is also applied temporarily with the code you're using:

```objc
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setBacklightLevel:BrightnessSlider.value];
```

The *combination* of these two changes should get you what you want.

Comment: I tried to use it, Pillst indeed changed. But after lock / unlock screen brightness is restored to whatever brightness is set in iOS Settings，too.

Comment: Modify system settings brightness, then GSEventSetBacklightLevel set brightness, then the lock screen, then unlock, and then again GSEventSetBacklightLevel set to work.

Comment: @KID, Did this solve the problem for you?  If so, please **accept** the answer by clicking the little "V" icon next to this answer.  If not, let me know, and I'll see if I can help you further.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried to use it, Pillst indeed changed. But after lock / unlock screen brightness is restored to whatever brightness is set in iOS Settings.
I have to: 1.Settings -> Brightness change Brightness, 2.change slider's value, 3.lock screen and unlock, 4.change slider's value again. So that it can.----Translation from Google

Answer (score 0):

```
Class $SBBrightnessController = objc_getClass("SBBrightnessController");
[[$SBBrightnessController sharedBrightnessController] _setBrightnessLevel:BrightnessSlider.value showHUD:YES];
```

The joys of objective-c runtime :)